# Split a String on an Integer followed by a space

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a rather large `String` that i need to split so I can put it into an array.  As it is, there will be a semicolon followed by an `Integer`, followed by a space and this is where I need to split it.

Say for instance, I have a `String`:

```
 first aaa;0 second bbb;1 third ccc;2
```

I need to split it so that it becomes:

```
 first aaa;0 
 second bbb;1
 third ccc;2
```

I assume I can use something like:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(^([0-9]*\s");
 myArray = pattern.split(string_to_split);
```

I just don't understand RegEx that well yet.

Thanks to anyone taking a look

Also, the pattern where it should be split will always be a semicolon, followed by only one digit and then the space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just split your input string according to the below regex.

```
(?<=;\\d)\\s
```

Code:

```
String s = "first aaa;0 second bbb;1 third ccc;2";
String[] tok = s.split("(?<=;\\d)\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

Output:

```
[first aaa;0, second bbb;1, third ccc;2]
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=;\d)` Positive lookbehind is used here. It sets the matching marker just after to the `;<number>`. That is, it asserts what precedes the space character is must be  a semicolon and a number.
- `(?<=;\d)\s` Now it matches the following space character.
- Splitting your input string according to that matched space will give you the desired output.